# How do I programmatically add a user to the Access Permissions in DCOM Config

Tags: vb.net, com+, comadmin

I have created an installer using WIX and have a custom action to add my COM+ application using **COMAdminCatalog**. But what I would like to do is also configure the security for the Access Permissions. After install these use the default COM permissions, but I would like to customise these in my installer.

These can be changed manually using DCOMCNFG, under *Component Services\Computers\My Computer\DCOM Config*.

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwpCK.png)

How can I achieve this programmatically?

Thanks